# "Byte Patterns" in hbase rowkey design

Tags: java, encoding

from [Hbase rowkey design](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/rowkey.design.html)

I dont unstand the sample in "Byte Pattern":

```
 // hash
//
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] digest = md.digest(Bytes.toBytes(s));
System.out.println("md5 digest bytes length: " + digest.length);    // returns 16

String sDigest = new String(digest);
byte[] sbDigest = Bytes.toBytes(sDigest);
System.out.println("md5 digest as string length: " + sbDigest.length);    // returns 26
```

why sbDigent.length != digest.length ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in my eclipse,
"digest" is 0xE807F1FCF82D132F9BB018CA6738A19F, 16 bytes, so its length is 16.

"sbDigest" is 0xEFBFBD07EFBFBDEFBFBDEFBFBD2D132FEFBFBDEFBFBD18EFBFBD6738EFBFBDEFBFBD,34 bytes, so its length is 34 (**not 26**).

The root reason is java.lang.String's constructor:

public String(byte[] bytes)

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using
>   the platform's default charset. The length of the new String is a
>   function of the charset, and ***hence may not be equal to the length
>   of the byte array***.